# Full text search in poatgres using tsvector and tsquery

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, full-text-search

I have a query like below

```
Select * from abc where (to_tsvector('english', firstname) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'a:*'));
```

is not working

But same query aa is working

```
Select * from abc where (to_tsvector('english', firstname) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'aa:*'));
```

--working

Is there any error first query

Comment: "Not working" is never a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 1):

'a' is a stop-word in English, so it gets removed from the query leaving it empty.  You could get around this by using 'simple' rather than 'english', or by writing the query by hand `'a:*'::tsquery`.

The partial match feature doesn't get along well with stemming or stop words.  Using both of those things together will lead to such problems.